# LINQ - list group by

Tags: linq, lambda

I am having trouble with a class that has a list of objects - basically it is a shopping cart where you can add items. I wish for the items to be grouped by the item id, so they would not appear more times in the cart.

So if you add an item, and then you add it again, it should appear as 1 row, quantity =2, instead of 2 rows quantity 1.

First of all, is there a way of automatically organizing a list this way?

If not, then I need another var:

```
var l = from i in list.cartItems
group i by i.id into g
select g.ToList();

list.cartItems = l;
```

list is the object, cartItems is the list, l would be the new list to "refresh"

However, this causes me an error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit:
I edited the error

Cartitems is just:
public List cartItems;

inside a CartItemList class

Comment: can you provide declaration of `cartItems`?

Comment: yes, did it, but it is just a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the grouped element you want, like this:

```
list.cartItems = l.First();
```

Your cartItems is a '**ListOfItems**' type, and your var l is a new grouped type, which is '**int,ListOfItems**' type. So to cast your '**int,ListOfItems**' to cartItems which is '**ListOfItems**', you should choose the element some element from your result collection.

Comment: This only gets the first item, how do I get them all? There is no error at least, thanks!

Comment: @user1479059 You sould not cast it to list.cartItems. Just use the result l collection. Why do you want to cast it to cartItems? It has no sence because they are two different collections.

Comment: well I'm kind of a noob so I dont understand this stuff so well... Even what you just said, I have no idea

Comment: @user1479059 You seems to not understand well what you are doing. You have some items in your shop. Then you group them by model. It becomes a collection of model, which contains a subcollection of your items. And then you try to cast back this new collection of subcollections to the first collection. The collection of items and the grouped by model collection of items are two different things, and you can't cast one to another. You can only choose some subcollection from the grouped one and cast it to base item collection, because they are the same things.

Answer (score 0):

for solve you need change select clause in your query - in select you can apply aggregate function like this:

```
var l = (from i in list.cartItems
        group i by i.id into g
        select new CartItem(){Id=g.Key, quantity=g.Count()}).ToList();

list.cartItems = l;
```

try sample that work

```
var t = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new { Id = i % 3, Q = 1 }).ToList();
var b = from i in t
        group i by i.Id into g
        select new { Id = g.Key, Q = g.Count() };
t = b.ToList();
```

and check your inputs

Comment: Suppose this won't work becasue, CartItem has no quantity property.

Comment: @voo sure, this a sample, i'm don't know what is `CartItem`

Comment: Yes, now all items I add are displayed, but no matter what the quantity is only 1... there is a q instead of quantity

Comment: yes but why is the quantity of each item only 1 - so if I add 1 book and then the same book again, it should be 2... it is as though the Count is not working how it should

Comment: can you provide sample input `cartItems`? if you groupped by unique field in each group will be one element

Comment: also you can try use `Sum` instead of `Count` if Q in your cartItem not only 1